# Unable to run top command in Linux after a few days of uptime

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-player

After 3 days uptime, I can't run `top` in Linux.

This is x86 Linux Fedora Core 8 running under vmWare under Windows XP.

```
[root@fc8 ]# uname -a
Linux fc8 2.6.23.1-42.fc8 #1 SMP Tue Oct 30 13:55:12 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

ps, uptime works fine.

Anyone have any suggestion on what might be the problem or how to diagnose it?

**Updates**:
There is no error message.  The "top" command just hangs there.

Also, one other problem I notice at the sametime was that `time somecommand` gives:

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The `somecommand` did take a few seconds to execute.

The system time in Linux under vmWare session is corrected.    I don't use the ntp to sync time.  I have a cron job to sync time with the `hwclock --hwtosys` command.

Comment: I think you might be more likely to find your answer at SuperUser.com

Comment: When you go there, be sure to bring with you the error message you're getting, or any information at all as to what actually happens.

Comment: superuser.com if it's just your personal machine, serverfault.com if it's server (and since it has few days uptime it's probably server)

Comment: try running "strace top" to see where top is getting stuck. It may give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

What is the VM's clock showing at these times? It could be something strange in what-ever combination of clock syncing (if any) is going on. If VMWare is slowing the VM's clock a lot to try account for what it thinks is the VM's time getting to far ahead then that might explain `time` returning a wall-clock time of 0 and top (which takes some readings, waits a second or so, takes some more readings, then updates its display) pausing waiting for the second(s) to tick over.

If the clock does seem to be where is shouldn't be: I find the most reliable way to keep VM clocks accurate is to make sure VMWare's clock sync options are *off* and use NTP with `tinker panic 0` at the top of the config file.

Comment: David, I use this to sync time instead of ntp.  I notice the hwclock in Linux always provide the right time.  I have issue with company firewall blocking the NTP.


[root@fc8 pogo]# crontab -l
# hourly to sync the hwclock
0-59 * * * *    /sbin/hwclock --hctosys
# Work day sync of NTP server at 11 am
* 11 * * 1,2,3,4,5      /usr/sbin/ntpdate 10.81.24.191

Comment: The time in Linux under vmWare is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Did you use a newly woken up vmware session? I noticed that the clock sometimes only restores to the correct time after something like a minute, although it feels a lot longer :-(. Did you check your (ntp?) time-service?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing and using htop - http://htop.sourceforge.net/

How log did you leave top sitting there?  Did you give it 10 minutes, for example?

Comment: This time, I reboot the system.  Previously, I have seen it hanged there for at lease a few hours.   

Reboot Linux in vmWare does solve the problem.

Comment: Just did a yum install htop, it is very nice.  

BTW, I might be able to use strace to track down deeper, will try that when I see it happen again.     

Thanks for suggestion and inspiration...